# Chromeless : while exists loop syntax

Tags: javascript, chromeless

I would like to execute a piece of code as long  as an element still exists in the DOM, but I can't find the correct syntax in Chromeless. Something like:

```
while (await chromeless.exists('div#ready')) {
    //// code
}
```

Can I use Chromeless to do that or do I need to use .evaluate somehow?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the code I posted above now works. The correct syntax is thus:

```
while (await chromeless.exists('div#ready')) {
    //// code
}
```